What is this blue dot next to my files in the sidebar of Sublime Text?
the blue dots on the sidebar
I tried search what its for but I couldn't find anything and I want to know if its for a problem or something and how I can fix/prevent it, since I'm pretty new to Sublime Text and coding in general.
I tried clicking on it and right clicking on it but nothing really special happened that caught my eye.
Thanks in advance!

one of the first google results for the title

I tried saving it and it didn't change. Plus when a file has unsaved changes I've noticed that there is a gray dot on the other side of the sidebar that goes away when I save it. The file is definitely saved as I need to save it to run the code, so it can't be that. I appreciate your comment, though!

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/signs-next-to-the-file-name-whats-meaning/50945, more specifically (changed as far as Git is concerned)

oh that makes sense because i recently learnt how to use git and integrated it into that directory, thanks

Pretty sure it means those files are modified.

Ah, thank you! I tried to look it up but couldn't find anything for some reason.

Those are what sublime text uses to show you the current git status of yhe file and it's folder, which may be:

unstaged
commited
stashed
uptodate.

If you use a git client like git, or sublime merge you may easily make changes to that, and if you are new to git.
Those signs on the side which could be

a dot blue: modified
circle: untract
a red dot : not found
...
Read the docs at:  https://sublimetext.com/docs/git_integration.html

